# Rewrite u=something to /something/ in Apache web server

Tags: php, apache, url-rewriting, httpd.conf

I have got the following URL: `website.com/users?u=username`. Can I rewrite it to `website.com/users/username/`?

I have tried this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

But it only changes `users.php` to /users/

Answer (score 1):

Try this (I haven't tested it):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^users\.php?u=(.*)$ /
RewriteRule ^/users/(.*)/?$ /users.php?u=$1 [NC]
```

It should internally redirect requests for `/users/username/` to `/users.php?u=username`.

If you also want to redirect `/users.php?u=username` to `/users/username/`, try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/users.php?u=(.*)$ /users/$1/ [R=301]
```

Comment: @RealSlimShady Is that from the first or second rule?

Comment: Second  but i did not try first

Comment: I am not sure. Is you mod_rewrite enabled? `sudo a2enmod mod_rewrite`